# Another CoreData fetch optimization

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, query-optimization, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a database of "**Product**" entities, roughly 40k - 500k entries. I have a view that allows the user to scroll through a table of the entities (I know bad design but that's what the customer wants).

The "**Product**" entity looks like this:

```
**Product:** 
     - part_number (string) (indexed)
     - list_price (string)
     - manufacturer_partNumber (string)
     - productDescription (string)
     - productID (string)
     • inventory (NSManagedObject, 1..n)
         - name (string)
         - quantity (string)
     • manufacturer (NSManagedObject, 1..1)
         - name (string)
         - manufacturerID (string)
```

At first I had the `NSFetchedResultsController` created in the standard way returning all the **Product** entities with the sort descriptor is set on `part_number`. I jumped through all the hoops to try and speed up the fetching:

1. fetchBatchSize
2. Indexing the properties
3. [EXPLAIN QUERY](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html)

Doing this I was only able to get the fetching down to about ~3.5min. Not good.

So from EXPLAIN QUERY I saw that a lot of time was spent fetching the `inventory` and `manufacturer` entities. Reasonable but still not good. So I decided to move to only returning some properties of the **Product** entity instead of who thing.

Here are the properties that I am fetching with `setPropertiesToFetch`

```
 - part_number (string) (indexed)
 - list_price (string)
 - photo (string)
 - productID (string)
```

Which the sort descriptor is set on `part_number` with the `fetchBatchSize` at 15. This cuts the fetch time down to ~40sec. Still not good.

---

I know someone will ask here is how I setup the `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsControllerWithCacheName:(NSString*)cacheName {

    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:cacheName];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"part_number" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:15];

    [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"part_number", @"list_price", @"photo", @"productID"]];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                                                  managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                                             cacheName:cacheName];

    return theFetchedResultsController;
}
```

---

Is there *anything* else that I can do to speed this up?

One idea that I had that maybe really hacky is to do some type of lazy loading with the NSFetchedResultsController (yes I know it's suppose to handle it). I haven't fully thought this through but setting the `setFetchLimit` to say 100 and use a NSPredicate to load stuff after the last `part_number`. This may be just a time consuming.

Comment: you can try fetching your object by small groups (e.g. 1000) by setting fetch request's fetchLimit to 1000 objects and every time you need new entries execute fetch request with new fetchOffset (for the first request - 0, second request - 1000, etc.)

Comment: When you call `performFetch:` on the controller, that will actually execute a couple of SQL queries. Can you also paste those queries and the output of EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN for each query?

Comment: Isn't the NSManagedObjectResultType a better choice here? Fetched results controller could leave those objects that are not on screen as faults.